# manipulate DOM of popup.html from background.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

code in background.js to manipulate DOM in popup.html

```
var views = chrome.extension.getViews({type: "popup"});
for (var i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
    views[i].document.getElementById('loginwindow').style.display="none";
    for (var key in userdata) {
      if (userdata.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         views[i].document.getElementById('projs').innerHTML += "<input value='"+key+"' type='checkbox' /> " + userdata[key] + "<br/>"; 
      }
    }                    
}
```

`userdata` is a JSON Object like this:

```
{"1":"test projekt",
 "4":"Second Project",
 "5":"Third Project",
 "6":"Fourth Project",
 "7":"5th one",
 "8":"6th one dude"}
```

There is a login box in popup.html

[image]

After my code above, popup.html is changing to this, because i am rendering those project names from JSON and putting them in popup.html in the for loop above:

[image]

But the problem is: Once I click the icon again, again the login window is showing up, not the manipulated one. How can i achieve this, where the manipulated one stays permanently there?

this is the html code inside popup.html where i try to render the checkboxes:

```
<div id="projs">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using two different pages and calling

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "popup2.html"})?
```

Comment: You only put the default popup in the manifest. You can set any of your html pages as the popup.

Comment: ah cool. now i am testing this like this: 
``chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "popup2.html"});
  var views = chrome.extension.getViews({type: "popup"});`` But it is still changing the first popup.html and opening the second one, weird :(

Comment: Oh, i am reading in the doc, it says: ``it sets the html document to be opened as a popup when the user clicks on the browser action's icon.``. so only **when** user clicks the icon, then it will switch the templates

Comment: This will last until Chrome is closed. You need to use chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener() and set the browser action again.

Comment: I need to change the template **not** depending on click on icon. so not with _browserAction_. is there any other popup setter?